# Editing an oracle export file in java

Tags: java, file, io, binary

My requirement is to change some text in exp file.

```
string = reader.readLine(); //content of file 
string .replaceAll("x", "Y");
//write string to file.
```

I think it might create a file with garbage values. It shouldn't be treated as text file. So, Please help me in

- Type of Stream to choose (Byte, Character, Buffer)
- Any encoding /decoding required
- what could be the size of BUFFER to avoid missing any content that needs to be replaced.
- can I even read binary files line by line just like text files.

Comment: Can you open this file in any text editor? if yes, can you please paste some sample content here for understanding? How do you open such files?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  What is the requirement? AFAIK oracle export files are binary and cannot be modified. Or rather you can modify them but no guarantees that you can then import them into Oracle.

Comment: chrisl08, exporting some prod data to test env that requires to map few confidential data with test data (eg creditcards).

Comment: Baddie, something like INSERT INTO "XXXXXXXXXXX" ("NEXT_ACCOUNT_NO") VALUES (:1)
        Á  ÿÿ
ANALSTATS TS "XXXXXXXXXXX"

Comment: "can I even read binary files line by line just like text files" - most binary formats I know of don't have such things as "lines".